# Help, I mamed the RPI's networking drivers, and now I can't get it back to normal!

Tags: networking, pi-4

everyone, I messed up my RPI4B's wifi and networking software. BAD.

Long story short , I followed a bunch of guides on how to host and connect to a wifi network at the same time [(ethernet - acces point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge/89804#89804), as well as how to host a wifi network and get a ethernet/wifi bridge running [(Turn your raspberry pi 3 into a wifi hotspot)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgcDipALFOc)

Both of these guides, I followed to the letter, and now, the networking and WiFi drivers are a tangled mess of packages that have nothing to do with each other. (for example: I accidently set up two ethernet/wifi bridges!). I want it back to normal, because my project didn't work (and I want it organised, so it isn't a hodgepodge of random packages!) The problem is that I have no idea how to revert it back to normal!

I guess my question in whole is this: how were the RPI's networking drivers set up at factory default, and how do I get them back that way?

Here is my OS version data, I just used the "full-upgrade"
command, today.

```
~ $ cat /etc/os-release
```

PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

Comment: Just restore from your backup. If you don't have one you have learned a valuable lesson; do a fresh install.

Comment: Two points: **1 :** In RPi, you have `image-backup` - an [excellent backup tool](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A83790+image-backup) - If you go for a *"wander in the woods"* it's like [Hansel & Gretel's breadcrumbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hansel_and_Gretel), but no worries about the birds. **2 :** In general, "configuration risks" increase over time. Debian is not a fast-moving distro, but the configuration guide you followed was published during [*"early Buster"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_OS#Release_history).

Comment: Oh, well. I guess I will do a fresh install.
Thanks for the backup tip

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Ingo's tutorials tell users to delete "unnecessary" network components so it is not possible to "get them back" (at least until you have a working network).

If you want to persist with `systemd-networkd` the simplified tutorial explains one method to setup [Basic networking using systemd-networkd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117843/8697)

Comment: I wonder if an edit should be made to @ingo Q&A? I say this because he last updated it during [early days of **`buster`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_OS#Release_history), I'm not sure he's still interested in maintaining it and don't know if anyone else is willing and able to do so. He's still about - [his user page](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/79866/ingo) shows he visited sometime during the past week, but no activity in nearly a year.... are you still there Ingo??